ValueError: Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket
I'll try to explain in great detail what is my problem and how the project is structured.
I want to make a real time chat applications.
So far my project has:
SignupLoginApp
ProgettoDiGruppo (Main app)
Home
ChatManagement(Websocket app).

Now the problem is I can't get the websocket to run and since it's my first time I don't really know what I'm doing.
Here is my ProgettoDiGruppo.settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [`
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ThirdParty
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',
    'channels',
    # MyApp
    'SignupLoginApp.apps.SignupappConfig',
    'Home.apps.HomeConfig',
    ChatManagement.apps.ChatmanagementConfig'
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProgettoDiGruppo.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'ProgettoDiGruppo.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    default': {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
    }
}

Here is my ProgettoDiGruppo.routing.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import ChatManagement.routing


websocket_urlpatterns = [

]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(`
            ChatManagement.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})

This is my ChatManagement.routing.py
`from django.urls import re_path
from ChatManagement import consumers
websocket_urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'/ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]`
ChatMAnagement.consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': self.scope['user'].username
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # This method will be called when a 'chat_message' event is received
        message = event['message']
        # Send the message to the WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=message)

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

This is the log of django after I've run ./manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 10, 2024 - 00:28:29
Django version 5.0.4, using settings 'ProgettoDiGruppo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

This is the daphne comand I run
daphne -p 8001 ProgettoDiGruppo.asgi:application
I go with 8001 because 8000 is taken from the webserver already
daphne gives me this log when I try to run the js to connect to the websocket:
127.0.0.1:60038 - - [10/Apr/2024:00:31:45] "WSCONNECTING /ws/chat/fffd/" - -
2024-04-10 00:31:46,000 ERROR    Exception inside application: Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/asgi.py", line 165, in __call__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket.
127.0.0.1:60038 - - [10/Apr/2024:00:31:46] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/chat/fffd/" - -

at the same time I don't get errors on the Django log which gives me this:
[10/Apr/2024 00:31:45] "GET /home/chat/fffd/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3571
[10/Apr/2024 00:31:45] "GET /static/js/websocket.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

And lastly this is the js code for the WebSocket Connection
chatSocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
    const data = JSON.parse(evt.data)
    console.log(data)
}

I want to get the Websocket Working in order to achieve real time chat features.
*Edit: I thought you needed backticks in every line

Need to see your asgi.py file
